# Is it possible to migrate your db(users login credentials) to ethereum private network?

Tags: private-blockchain, privacy, database, hyperledger

I am thinking of migrating db to any of blockchain technologies for security purposes. I have to opt from hyperledger or ethereum private network. Is it good idea or any trades off I should be aware of.

Comment: What kind of db?

Comment: Nosql db, it contains users login info.